# Efficient random array of probability weights that sum 1

Tags: r, random, probability

I need something very simple and it seems to me that my solution has too many steps (considering that R is done for statistics):

All I need is an array of N probability weights (between 0 and 1) that sum up to one. What would be an easy and/or efficient solution?

My solution:

```
N <- 40
weights <- runif(40)
f <- 1/sum(weights) 
weights <- f*weights
print(sum(weights))
```

Comment: `prop.table(runif(N))`

Comment: You're adding an extra step. Why not just; `weights <- runif(40); w <- weights / sum(weights)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

You can use [prop.table](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/prop.table) function and [runif](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/Uniform) function:

```
weights <- prop.table(runif(N))
```

Which is the same as running

```
w <- runif(N); weights <- w / sum(w)
```

**Explanation:**

1. `runif` function generates `N` random numbers in range from 0 to 1
2. `prop.table` rescales them, so that sum is equal to 1 (does the same as w / sum(w))

Comment: Thanks, was in the comments, but poster didnt bother to post an answer. here you go and get the tick.