# generating a discrete random probability distribution, by perturbing an existing one

Tags: r, algorithm, random, probability

If I wanted to efficiently generate a **random** discrete probability distribution of N probabilities which sum up to 1, I could go with Hadley's comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20018197/efficient-random-array-of-probability-weights-that-sum-1):

```
prop.table(runif(N))
```

If I repeat this many times, the average probability for each of the N elements should be ~1/N.

What if I want the average probability for each of the N elements not to be 1/N but a specified number *a priori*?

E.g. `N = 4` elements, I have the `apriori` distribution:

```
apriori <- c(0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.4)
```

And I would like random distributions *based on this a priori*, e.g.:

```
c(0.21, 0.29, 0.12, 0.38)
c(0.19, 0.29, 0.08, 0.44)
c(0.19, 0.33, 0.1, 0.38)
```

Etc.

Where we go by either of these rules:

1) On average each of the elements probabilities would be (approx.) its probability in the a priori distribution

2) There's a "perturbation" parameter, say `perturbation = 0.05` which means either: (a) we're letting each of the probabilities `i` to be in the `apriori[i] +- perturbation` range or (b) we're letting each of the probabilities `i` to be in the `apriori[i] +- perturbation * apriori[i]` range (i.e. plus/minus 5% of that apriori probability, not absolute 5%)

I have no idea how to do this while keeping rule 1.

Regarding rule 2, my initial inefficient thought would be perturbing each of the first N - 1 elements by a random allowed amount, setting the last element to be `1 - sum(N-1_probs)` and wrapping this with a while loop until the last element is also legitimate.

I didn't even implement it yet because that's very inefficient (say I want 100K of such distributions...). Ideas?

Comment: you might want to look at the [Dirichlet distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As proposed by prof.Bolker, you ought to look at [Dirichlet distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution). Let's denote mean apriori values by capital letters C<sub>i</sub> and sampled values by small letters c<sub>i</sub>. It will automatically, from distribution properties, provide you with two features:

1. Sum <sub>i</sub> c<sub>i</sub> = 1
2. Each c<sub>i</sub> is within [0...1] range

so right away you could use them as probabilities.

Given C<sub>i</sub>, and looking at distribution definition (check the link), the only free parameter left is

a<sub>0</sub> = Sum <sub>i</sub> a<sub>i</sub>

and each a<sub>i</sub> = C<sub>i</sub> * a<sub>0</sub>

Such choice of a<sub>i</sub> will (again, automatically) provide proper mean value E[c<sub>i</sub>] = C<sub>i</sub>.

Bigger a<sub>0</sub> - c<sub>i</sub> would be more narrow around C<sub>i</sub>. Variance is roughly speaking Var[c<sub>i</sub>] ~ C<sub>i</sub>/a<sub>0</sub>, so for 5% you might try to use a<sub>0</sub> of 50.

Some R code

```
library(MCMCpack)

apriori <- c(0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.4) # your C_i
a0 <- 50
a <- a0*apriori

set.seed(12345)
# sample your c_i and use it, for example, to throw uneven dice
ci <- rdirichlet(1, a)
dice <- rmultinom(1, 1, ci)

# another dice throw
ci <- rdirichlet(1, a)
dice <- rmultinom(1, 1, ci)

...
```

Comment: Thank you so much. If I treat my `perturbation` as the desired standard deviation I can reach a simple rule of thumb like `a0 <- exp(-20 * perturbation + 5)` and reach good results approximately for cases I have tested. [parameters achieved by getting good values for `a0` and regressing `log(a0)` against `perturbation`.]

Comment: @GioraSimchoni Glad to hear. FYI, rdirichlet() implementation is based upon prof.Bolker code

Answer (score 1):

and using a normal distribution for each of your probability ?

```
perturbation <- 0.05
plouf <- sapply(apriori,function(x){max(rnorm(1,mean = x, sd = perturbation*x),0)})
plouf <- plouf/sum(plouf)
> plouf
[1] 0.2020629 0.3057111 0.0994482 0.3927778
```

Comment: That's beautiful, you could change the `unlist(lapply(...))` with `sapply`.

Comment: Those do not add up to 1 though, you might need to normalize them.

Comment: @denis another problem could be negative probabilities. You can fix it with `plouf <- sapply(apriori,function(x){max(rnorm(1, mean = x, sd = perturbation * x), 0)})`

Comment: @Giora Simchoni goog point. I edited the answer. I hope it suits your need. If it does you can accept the answer :)

Comment: And what final distribution would be? In the denominator you have sum of gaussians which is gaussian. In the nominator you have gaussian (which is actually correlated with denominator, but lets forget that for a moment). Dividing two gaussians should produce something like Cauchy, which is a big no-no in simulations

Comment: @denis thank you for your answer. I have accepted Severin's answer due to the sound(er) theoretical base and the fact the in practice indeed I see Cauchy-like distributions around the mean and this method is problematic for "stepping-out" of the mean, to get a "wider" and more varied distribution.

Comment: @GioraSimchoni and you did well, his answer is way better

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution, but it will end up with the draws being normal. I think you can probably do something similar to draw a uniform distribution. Don't have much experience with this, but I would lean towards a rejection kind of policy where you draw lots of things quickly, and then reject the ones that don't fit your criteria

```
rm(list = ls())

library(parallel)
library(data.table)
library(tictoc)

# set up the distribution informatoin
P <- 4
values <- 1:P
dist_scores <- data.table(param = values,
                          prob = c(0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.4), key = "param")
perturbation <- 0.05
method = "a"

switch (method,
  "a" = {dist_scores[, min := prob - perturbation]
    dist_scores[, max := prob + perturbation]},
  "b" = {dist_scores[, min := prob * (1-perturbation)]
    dist_scores[, max := prob * (1+perturbation)]}
)

# turn this in to a set of data that can be sampled
N <- 10000
v <- unlist(sapply(values, FUN = function(x){
  rep(x, round(dist_scores$prob[x]*N, 0))
}))
table(v)/N

# set number of samples, and number of draws for each iteration
sams <- 10000
reps <- 200

tic()
# loop through and draw reps from the sample. Rejection policy will remove
# ones that dont meet the conditions
new_iters <- mclapply(1:sams, FUN = function(x){
  y <- data.table(param = sample(v, reps, replace = TRUE))
  out <- y[, .(val = .N/reps), keyby = param]
  out <- dist_scores[out,]
  if(out[,all(val >= min & val <= max)]){
    return(out[, c("param", "val"), with = FALSE])
  }else{
    return(NULL)
  }
})
reject_rate <- sum(sapply(new_iters, is.null))/sams
# number of samples
sams - reject_rate*sams
toc()

out <- rbindlist(new_iters)

par(mfrow = c(2,2))
for(i in values){
  hist(out[param == i, val])
}enter code here
```